# Spring data jpa collection don`t update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

Hi I have 2 entities: Department and User.

I find both entities and want to add one to the other
But if I add a user to the department, the user has Department = null.
And if the opposite is true, then List = null.
How to do this correctly?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 36, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;


    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 36, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;


    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "device_devices",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "device_id"))
    Set<Device> devices = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equal(id, user.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }
}
```

And **service**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addUserToDepartment(UUID departmentId,UUID userId){
    Department department = departmentRepository.findById(departmentId).orElseThrow(DepartmentNotFoundException::new);
    User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);
    department.getUsers().add(user);
    //user.setDepartment(department);
}
```

It seems to me that adding user to department and simultaneously adding department to user is not correct. They have to pull themselves up.
Help Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is why you have `mappedBy` attribute. It hints to hibernate what side will be responsible for those mappings **when you have a bi-directional ascosiation**.

So considering your configuration

```
public class Department {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
    }
```

Then setting the mapping only on User on field department would be enough

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addUserToDepartment(UUID departmentId,UUID userId){
    Department department = departmentRepository.findById(departmentId).orElseThrow(DepartmentNotFoundException::new);
    User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);
    //department.getUsers().add(user); You don't need this.
    user.setDepartment(department); This here is enough for hibernate!
}
```

### BUT

as pointed out by hibernate documentation in order to have normal java usage inside a method you need to manually update both sides. This means that if you update only 1 side then the changes will be persisted on DB level but on java level your other instance will not be synced with those changes.

Check the following examples on hibernate documentation (**Example 297**, **Example 298**) [Hibernate Bi directional mapping normal java usage](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement)

Answer (score 1):

Bi-directional relationship has to be maintained manually by you, there is no magic that happens behind the scenes to deal with that for you.

An alternative to dealing with that in service code would be to enhance setters of the joining properties to handle that instead, for instance on User side:

```
public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
    department.getUsers().add(this);
}
```

See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Getters_and_Setters) for documentation.

Comment: I seem to do the same thing in the service, don't I?
 ```Department department = departmentRepository.findById(departmentId).orElseThrow(DepartmentNotFoundException::new);
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);
        department.getUsers().add(user);```

Comment: If you uncomment the line you have commented out, yes, that's what you do in the code from your question.

Comment: I think you're wrong. Because if I add a department to the user. Then the user will have a department_id in the database. Accordingly, when scanning, the user and the department should update the communication states

Comment: They will, if you merge. If doing additional DB query just to have the state synced is ok for you you can do that as well. But if you want the state correct as is, you need to do that manually.